# Updating and displaying counter variable value within an #each block

Tags: javascript, each, svelte

I'm having a tough time solving what seems to be a relatively simple problem. I'm being thrown off by svelte's reactivity feature.

Within an #each block, I need to update and display the value of an increasing "counter" after each iteration. Unfortunately passing in the counter variable updates all the iterations values to the latest count.

Is there a way to "bake" the value of the variable into each iteration instead of them only referencing the variable?

```
<!-- the console log shows the desired result instead of the "6" value for every iteration -->
<script>
    let arr = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
    let counter = 0
    let increment = ()=>{
        counter++
        console.log(counter)
        return ""
    }
    const getCount = counter
</script>

{#each arr as item,i}
<p>
    {item} -> {counter}
</p>
{increment()}
{/each}

<!-- I cannot use the "i"  since in my actual code I have #if blocks within the #each blocks which can either increment the counter or reset the counter.-->
```

[Svelte REPL showing the issue.](https://svelte.dev/repl/b79217c8fdef4d8b908baf39f5baaa0f?version=3.50.1)

Any ideas?

Comment: return from `increment()`? `{item} -> {increment()}` or `{item} -> {i}` ? It's unclear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re trying to achieve, but you shouldn’t be calling functions inside the template that update state. That could lead to unexpected behavior in Svelte. There’s probably a more idiomatic way to do what you’re doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying state in an `#each` is not a good idea, as noted by
Geoff Rich this can lead to unexpected behavior.

You should associate each item with the appropriate index when you generate your data and then simply bind to the property that contains said index.